# WP7: TextBox with suggestions

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In the standard Windows Phone 7 apps, the soft keyboard offers you suggestions to complete the word you are typing.

When I create a WP7 app and add a normal TextBox control, these suggestions don't apprear. How do I get the TextBox to offer suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the [`InputScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscope%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for the `TextBox`; the *Text* `InputScope` turns on suggestions.

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.InputScope>
    <InputScope>
      <InputScopeName NameValue="Text" />
    </InputScope>
  </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

This [blog post](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/07/06/WP7-InputScope.aspx) has a list of the `InputScope`s available on the phone.

Comment: Works fine, thanks. It is even possible to enter the InputScope as an attribute: <TextBox InputScope="Text">

Comment: @Hinek It is, I prefer the long version myself because Intellisense auto-complete is not available in the other case.